# Why my type checking function doesn't type check?

Tags: typescript

This code:

```
const getImg = (images: string[] | IImage[], idx: number) => {
  if (typeof images[idx] == "string") {
    return images[idx];
  } else if (typeof images[idx] == "object") {
    return images[idx].image;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Error is property image does not exists on type 'string' | 'Image'.
Because of index this doesn't work. This is happens because  ts doesn't know -  has array element with this index or not? How can I solve this error?

Comment: maybe try using `instanceof` instead of `typeof`? I only know this should be typeguard, but I'm not sure which one suits your case

Comment: What is `IImage`?  Could you please [edit] to make the code a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs without references to external/private code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

will be very happy if my answer will help you.
You can assign that certain image to some variable (in my example img) and than do checks with that type.

```
interface IImage {
  image: string
}


const getImg = (images: string[] | IImage[], idx: number) => {
  const img = images[idx]
  if (typeof img == "string") {
    return img;
  } else if (typeof img == "object") {
    return img.image;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking if `image` exists in the object and using type assertion `as`, you can resolve the error related to the property `image` not existing on type `'string' | 'Image'`.

```
const getImg = (images: string[] | IImage[], idx: number) => {
  if (typeof images[idx] === "string") {
    return images[idx] as string;
  } else if (typeof images[idx] === "object" && "image" in images[idx]) {
    return (images[idx] as IImage).image;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```